# KB5023152 - System Restore broke many Windows Store apps, how to fix Store?

Tags: windows, system-restore, windows-store

I recently tried to use System Restore on a malfunctioning Windows 11 machine, and was bit by [KB5023152](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5023152-this-app-can-t-open-error-message-after-running-system-restore-and-then-starting-a-windows-app-in-windows-10-and-later-versions-52d63063-a912-4b2b-b0b8-a934d18625bf), which has prevented many of my apps from executing. Some I don't care about or can find work-arounds for (e.g. installing from non-Store sources), but others like WSL distributions or Windows Terminal are very difficult or inconvenient to maintain this way.

Unfortunately, the Store itself is one of the affected apps, and I can't get it working again. This breaks most of the other recommended fixes! Things I have tried:

- Simply giving it time, trying multiple times across reboots.
- Windows Update
- Windows Store Apps troubleshooter (finds no problems)
- Reinstall the Store via `winget` (`winget` is also broken!)
- Attempting "Repair" via Settings -> Apps (worked for a few things but the bar never completes progress for the Store, or Winget, and can't even find my WSL distro anymore)
- Attempting "Reset" via same (same outcome)
- Running `wsreset.exe` (fails because it tries to invoke the URI `ms-windows-store:PurgeCaches` and the handler for `ms-windows-store:` URIs is the Store app, which can't launch)
- Attempting to re-register the app using Powershell (`Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.WindowsStore | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}`  has no effect)
- Attempting to uninstall the Windows Store via Powershell (works) and then reinstall it using the MSIX bundle downloaded from the Store's content server (re-adds the Store to Start and re-registers the URI handler, but doesn't fix the problem).

At this point, I'm running up against the question of which is less hassle: continuing to operate with a crippled Windows installation that can't run commands and features I've come to rely on (like `winget` and WSLv2) in the hopes that MSFT fixes their mess, or re-installing the operating system and re-installing + re-configuring the half-TB of software I've installed (yes, it really is mostly software... admittedly, mostly games).

**Is there a better way?** Either to get the Store working again, or Winget working again, or some other way to fix apps, or similar? I've considered trying to do a "repair installation" of Windows (by doing an "upgrade" installation to the same version) but I'm not sure that will work or even be possible; I'm already on the latest released version so I can't get install media for anything that even has as many patches as my machine currently does, unless I go to an Insider build or wait for the next big update to drop without installing updates in the meantime. If it's likelier to be less mess and reinstallation/reconfiguration than a clean install, and to actually fix anything (will it? "keep your apps" is not entirely appealing when the problem is that many apps *don't work*), I guess it's the next thing to try, but I wanted to ask advice before I kept trying things.

This advisory came out almost a month ago now, but I've heard nothing further from MSFT. Does anybody have a workaround or fix?

Comment: I've considered trying to do a "repair installation" of Windows    ....  I suggest you try this. Media Creation Link, second link, download a file to a USB key, Run setup and that creates a Windows 11 repair App that will repair your system. Use the Keep Everything option initially.

Comment: Why don’t you just perform an in-place repair install, you keep all your files and installed applications, only draw back is that it’s not guaranteed to solve the problem. I assume you perform a restoration of a system repair point hence the reason you linked to a support article about the side effects of performing one

Comment: @John I guess it's worth a shot. The builds downloaded by the media creation tool are always deeply out of date, in my experience, to the point of sometimes not even having network or SSD drivers for recent hardware (ran into that recently; in 20+ years of Windows installing, I'd never had to use the "Install Drivers" button at the disk partitioning screen before!) I'm worried that kind of "repair downgrade" might interact poorly, but I guess it's worth a shot.

Comment: Use the Windows 11 Media Creation tool and it should be the current build. I have used this approach numerous times

Comment: "current build" means the "major update" version that was released between 1 and 7 months ago, typically (given delays between software RTM and rollout via Windows Update), and is currently from 20 Sep. I have personally been bitten, in the last two months, by Media Creation Tool builds not including drivers for current hardware. But I suppose a repair installation probably won't have that problem, and I'll make sure I have the drivers on hand anyhow. I'm just worried that it'll be missing updates I've already installed, and that will cause a problem, but if you've done it before...